# Use Standard Acrobat to programmatically combine PDF file?

Tags: pdf-generation, acrobat

There are lots of suggestions on SO and elsewhere for using non-Adobe products to programmatically combine PDF files.

Is there no way to (fairly easily) use my paid copy of Adobe Acrobat Standard (not Reader) to programmatically combine two or more PDF files into a new PDF file (I know it can be done manually with combine -> multiple files)?

Would prefer a command (e.g., copy file1.pdf file2.pdf combined.pdf), but would be willing to resort to VBA.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MergePDFs(nDocs As Integer, BaseFileName As String)

    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim iDoc As Integer

    Dim BaseDocument As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim PartDocument As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

    Dim numPages As Integer

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set BaseDocument = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Set PartDocument = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")


    BaseDocument.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & BaseFileName & "_" & 1 & ".pdf")
    For iDoc = 2 To nDocs
        PartDocument.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & BaseFileName & "_" & iDoc & ".pdf")
        numPages = BaseDocument.GetNumPages()

        ' Insert the pages of Part after the end of Base
        If BaseDocument.InsertPages(numPages - 1, PartDocument, 0, PartDocument.GetNumPages(), True) = False Then
            MsgBox "Cannot insert pages"
        End If
        PartDocument.Close
    Next iDoc
    If BaseDocument.Save(PDSaveFull, ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & BaseFileName & ".pdf") = False Then
        MsgBox "Cannot save the modified document"
    Else
        ' Remove intermediate documents
        For iDoc = 1 To nDocs
            Kill ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & BaseFileName & "_" & iDoc & ".pdf"
        Next iDoc
    End If
    BaseDocument.Close

    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroApp = Nothing
    Set BaseDocument = Nothing
    Set PartDocument = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no VBA for Acrobat. VBA is a Microsoft thing (and is apparently going away soon from what I've read [edit: strike that; apparently it's still alive and well in Office 2010]).

The [Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/) will allow you to automate Acrobat and do what you want to do, but it's *not* for the faint of heart. It may be easier (short-term, anyway) to use one of the free solutions you've read about elsewhere.